# What is the correct usage of wake_up_interruptible() in linux kernel 4.12?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have two functions, the kernel thread which blocks on

```
Work Kernel Thread()
{
 set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
wait_event_interruptible(..work.queue, condition)
  __set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
}

ISR
{

  wake_up_interruptible(..work queue..)
}
```

However, when I execute, the kernel complains that the

```
  WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 565 at /usr/src/kernel/kernel/sched/core.c:6234 __might_sleep+0x78/0x9c 
    do not call blocking ops when !TASK_RUNNING; state=1 set at 0x...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wait_event_interruptible()` macro expects the current task state to be `TASK_RUNNING` and the task state is changed back to `TASK_RUNNING` when execution returns to the caller. Therefore, the preceding call `set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);` and the subsequent call `__set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);` should be removed.

During execution of the `wait_event_interruptible()` macro the supplied `condition` will be evaluated one or more times, initially in the `TASK_RUNNING` state, and subsequently when woken up in the `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state.

The `wait_event_interrubtible()` macro returns `-ERESTARTSYS` if interrupted by a signal before the `condition`, or returns 0 when the `condition` evaluates to true.